# Why is my 2minute animation taking 5 days to render

Tags: rendering

It's been rendering for 5 days and still going... It's only 2minute animation with music

Comment: Its hard to guide you without any details of the render. Please explain properly in the question about what you are animating, level of details, simulations if any, settings of the render. or share the pics/file... Btw, are you rending frm sequencer?

Comment: it will depend on a lot of factors: render engine, resolution, sampling, complexity of your scene (number of objects and lights)...

Comment: Only five days is not too bad... It could take 10 days or 5 months... depending on the complexity of the scene, number of vertices/edges/faces, particles or physics simulations, your settings, image size, texture size, and more importantly the computing power at your disposal. 3D rendering takes time and resources (a lot  of them). Maybe you need to scale down your expectations to match your hardware, or optimize your scene. Hard to help you without knowing what kind of animation you are dealing with.

Comment: Welcome to the world of computer graphics! Currently rendering 4 seconds (100 frames, 1080p) which takes 20 days to render on one machine (24 cores).

Answer (score 1):

## Why?

It is normal that rendering takes a long time. You should expect that. This is the reason why animations are usually rendered on render farms using many powerful computers. If you are rendering 2 minutes in 4K at 30 frames per second for example, you have 2 x 60 x 30 = 3600 pictures to render and each of them has 3840 x 2160 = 8 294 400 pixels so that's a lot of pixels to compute. So say you are rendering with Cycles and use 2000 samples. Every one of those 8 294 400 pixels is checked 2000 times for every one of those 3600 pictures so that's really a lot of computation and will take a very long time on a single computer. It is often not practical to render on a single computer because it would take many years and there is no other option but to use tens or even hundreds of computers to render.

## What can you do

Obviously you may not afford to build a render farm yourself or to buy commercial render farm services since that is expensive, but you can look into [SheepIt](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/) for your hobby or even freelance projects. It is free in terms of money, but you still have to render projects for other people to collect points. This way you can render for the farm when you are not using your PC(at night for example) while you work on your animation and when the time comes, you can use the farm to render your project quickly. It has disadvantages compared to commercial solutions obviously like for example it is not that hard for other people to access your files, because they need to be sent for rendering and the farm is not that stable, it may experience technical issues more often than other solutions and there is a file size limit, it doesn't support some features like render passes and so on, but it can make certain things possible that wouln't be without it, so it's great.

Comment: Thank you all!! Very helpful!!! I had no idea!!! I thought that's how fast it was in the 90s and now it's 2020 but I'm completely if ignorant of the realities of tech/graphics because I don't work in that industry but I'm fascinated! Thank you again that helps!

Comment: It never gets faster as technology improves and most likely never will, it only gets more complex and more impressive...